# Help with incrementing an object index in for loop (its only writing the last object in the folder)

Tags: php, for-loop, counter

The script below is designed to scan a folder called "widgets" for its subfolders and the .txt files they contain. Each subfolder is a proxy for one of my theme's registed "sidebar widgets" and the .txt files in each folder are the "text widgets" that will be inserted into the registered sidebar represented by its parent folder.

The script is working fine to place a single text widget into each registered sidebar. However, when a folder contains multiple text files, its not incrementing the widget_id value as needed and the only text widget that gets written to the sidebar is the last one in the folder.

How can I set up a proper counter for the widget_id in this case?

```
/*Install Widgets from .txt files in child folders of "/widgets/"
-------------------------------------*/

$sidebars_widgets = get_option('sidebars_widgets');
$widget_ops = get_option('widget_text');
$widget_id = count($widget_ops)+1;


$base = dirname(__FILE__).'/widgets/';
$rdi = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($base);
foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($rdi) as $files_widgets) 
    {
     if ($files_widgets->isFile()) 
         {
            $file_name_widget = $files_widgets->getPathname();
            $sidebar_id = basename($files_widgets->getPath());
            $widget_text = file_get_contents($file_name_widget);
            $sidebars_widgets[$sidebar_id] = array("text-".$widget_id);
  //Do I need another loop here?
  //Only the last widget in the folder is created
            $widget_ops[$widget_id] = array('title' => $files_widgets->getBasename('.txt'),'text' => $widget_text,);
            update_option('widget_text', $widget_ops);  
            update_option('sidebars_widgets', $sidebars_widgets);
            $widget_id = $widget_id +1;
        }
    }
```

Background:
The "widgets" folder contains 5 folders, each representing a registered sidebar that my theme creates and named for the id of that sidebar.

For example, this sidebar is registered in functions.php

```
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'Home Sidebar',
    'id' => 'home-sidebar-widget',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="menu side %2$s sb">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h4 class="sidebarTitle">',
    'after_title' => '</h4>',
));
```

And the corresponding folder that contains all the widgets that will prepopulate that widget is...

`widgets/home-sidebar-widget/`

And it contains 3 .txt files, each representing a text widget that should be added to that sidebar.

The problem is that my counter for widget_id is not right apparently and I'm only getting the last .txt file in each folder written to the sidebar.

Comment: Your code seems fine but I don't know what the `update_option()` function do

Comment: Its a built in function to WordPress. It just updates the value of widget_text and passes the array in $widget_ops to the database. The code works fine, its just overwriting each file in the folder until it reaches the last one. That's the only one written to the database. Which makes me think I'm missing a counter or I need another loop.

Comment: Well in that case I'm guessing that `update_option()` will update the option named `widget_text` in the database with the the value you pass it. So at each iteration the same option is being updated and overwritten by the next one. Thus only the last one is kept in the DB. I suppose there is only one unique entry for the option `widget_text` and `sidebars_widgets`. Let me know if I'm wrong

Comment: See my answer below and let me know if that works for you

Comment: @sly: thanks! checking it out now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like that assuming that arrays are being serialized before being saved in the database and then unserialized when retrieved.

Try something like that

```
/*Install Widgets from .txt files in child folders of "/widgets/"
-------------------------------------*/

// Remove the line below as we will fetch the value in the loop
//$sidebars_widgets = get_option('sidebars_widgets');

$widget_ops = get_option('widget_text', array());
$widget_id = count($widget_ops) + 1;

$base = dirname(__FILE__).'/widgets/';
$rdi = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($base);
foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($rdi) as $files_widgets) 
{
     if ($files_widgets->isFile()) 
     {
            $file_name_widget = $files_widgets->getPathname();
            $sidebar_id = basename($files_widgets->getPath());
            $widget_text = file_get_contents($file_name_widget);

            // Retrieve the last value of the 'sidebars_widgets' option
            $sidebars_widgets = get_option('sidebars_widgets', array());

            // Add the current widget to the sidebar
            $sidebars_widgets[$sidebar_id][] = "text-".$widget_id;

            // Retrieve the last value of the 'widget_text' option
            $widget_ops = get_option('widget_text', array());

            // Add the new widget to the list of widgets
            $widget_ops[$widget_id] = array('title' => $files_widgets->getBasename('.txt'),'text' => $widget_text,);

            // Update the options with the updated arrays
            update_option('widget_text', $widget_ops);  
            update_option('sidebars_widgets', $sidebars_widgets);
            $widget_id = $widget_id + 1;
     }
}
```

**EDIT**
- Replaced `array_merge()` by the `+` operator

Comment: @Sly, I tried it both ways: straight (as is) and with your [$sidebar_id][] suggestion. The latter throws an error (strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string...)...continued...

Comment: ...The as is version does not error, but it does not work correctly either. What it does right, is that it does place all the widgets located in one of the folders into widgets. However, it writes them to the wrong sidebars. It places one widget into each sidebar, but they should all be in the same sidebar (since they are located in the same folder).

Comment: @Scott Yeah I understand. Try replacing `$sidebars_widgets[$sidebar_id][] = array("text-".$widget_id);` by `$sidebars_widgets[$sidebar_id][] = "text-".$widget_id;`. I have updated my answer's code accordingly. Let me know if that works.

Comment: @Sly: Me thinks we have a winner! Great work. Above and beyond. +1, If I could +100, i would.